# Mass Transit Queue Configuration when internet disconnects

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to hold data that is to be send to a DB, over the internet. One of the things is to not loose information that is to be sent to the DB if somehow we disconnect to the internet. Mass Transit, from my testing, will only hold one packet of information, so when internet is reconnected only that one packet will get resent. Optimally, I would like to be able to edit the queue size so that It can hold more than one packet of info. Am I able to do this, or will I have to create separate methods to correct for this. Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what this means: "Mass Transit, from my testing, will only hold one packet of information"?

Comment: What is your requirement actually? Your question is not obvious at all.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev the program collects data from a machine (e.g. a CNC) this data is then sent to a DB over the internet. When testing how to respond to an internet disconnect, the hope is to hold that data (one packet for each machine sending data) until internet is operational, at which point we will send the data over to the DB. While testing this, once the internet was disconnected we waited for a while ensuring more than one piece of data (packet) attempted to send, then reconnected the internet. Only 1 packet, was sent. Question is does MassTransit have something built in to change this?

Comment: @GregJenkins It sounds like you have an occasionally connected client and you really need towards a federated messaging set up, like MSMQ if you are on Windows. It has little to do with MassTransit. I suggest you read a little more about different types of messaging infrastructure here https://www.planetgeek.ch/2014/02/27/transport-transport-msmq-rabbitmq-activemq-with-nservicebus/